# Serving nested if in conditional panel of Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a conditional panel which renders radioButtons & a sliderInput based on selection. Radio buttons renders predefined frequencies and the slider input allows the user to select a range.

Based on the input range, I want to select age range. The server part of the code is:

```
if (input$Age == "Discrete Age Values" & input$slider1 == input$range[1]:input$range[2]) {
           s()[s()$Age >= input$range[1] & s()$Age <= input$range[2], ]
       }
```

"Slider1" is nested under "Discrete Age Values" as a condition.

However, this is gives me an error:

```
Error in input$range[1]:input$range[2] : argument of length 0
```

How do I define the range here?

Comment: What is this `input$slider1 == input$range[1]:input$range[2]` supposed to check? that input$slider1 is between input$rangep[1] and input$range[2] ?

Comment: @NicE Yes...slider1 has a range of 18 - 60, and input$range[1] and input$range[2] is supposed to check the location of the slider. Say if the input$range[1] is in 24 and input$range[2] in 30 I want to subset the database to these range values

Comment: Try && instead of & (not tested)